# Check numeric values from a dictionary by unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary

I have a function

> read_value_from_text()

that reads parameters from a config file and returns a dictionary in this form

```
{ key1 : value1, key2 : value2, ... , keyn : valuen }
```

the values (value1 ... valuen) are all strings that represent numbers. 
I want to write a unit test that checks if all values (value1,...,valuen) are "numeric" ( float or integer). Can someone suggest an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [test whether a string is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python) with:

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

is_number(x)
```

You can thus do:

```
self.assertTrue(all(is_number(v) for v in d.itervalues()))
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in the question...
value1... valuen are all string that rapresent numbers
Like '1' or '2.3'
In this case the function isinstance fails

Comment: @overcomer I understand now. Corrected (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python) for more on that function)

Answer (score 1):

```
def isNumeric(val):
    if isinstance(val, (int, float)):
        return True
    try:
        float(val)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Sample test:

```
d = {}
for v in d.itervalues():
    self.assertTrue(isNumeric(v))
```

Well, to be honest it's validator, not unit test. Unit tests are checking code behaviour, you're checking data correctness.

Answer (score 0):

```
for val in my_dict.values():
    self.assertIsInstance(val, int)
```

Comment: Will fail in case val is float, see OP.